# Running boinc client in kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, vagrant

my goal is to make cluster running on raspberry pi 4b.
Currently i'm trying/testing/playing with kubernetes in vagrant.
My project is here:
https://github.com/kentahikaru/vagranttraining/tree/master/kubernetes_testing

I am able to initialize master and connect node to the cluster.

However i'm having trouble deploying boinc client, the way i want it.
The deployment i am using is here:
https://github.com/kentahikaru/vagranttraining/blob/master/kubernetes_testing/Testing/boinc/boinc_client_deploy.yaml
The way it is uploaded on github, it is working. I can deploy it and it will switch into Running state.
However when i uncomment "command" and "args" (because i want it automatically connect to my accounts) it will crash and i can't figure out why:

```
vagrant@master:~$ kubectl get pods -o wide
NAME                           READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE   IP            NODE    NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
boincclient-69cdf887dc-7phr2   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   1          12s   10.244.2.69   node2   <none>           <none>
```

From the docker log on node (/var/log/containers) :

```
{"log":"can't connect to local host\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2020-11-11T22:27:35.708789661Z"}
{"log":"can't connect to local host\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2020-11-11T22:27:35.711018367Z"}
{"log":"can't connect to local host\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2020-11-11T22:27:35.714129251Z"}
{"log":"can't connect to local host\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2020-11-11T22:27:35.714160084Z"}
```

I can't also figure out why "kubectl logs" is not working:

```
vagrant@master:~$ kubectl -v=8 logs boincclient-69cdf887dc-7phr2
I1111 22:30:27.452750   31588 loader.go:375] Config loaded from file:  /home/vagrant/.kube/config
I1111 22:30:27.464024   31588 round_trippers.go:420] GET https://172.16.0.21:6443/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/boincclient-69cdf887dc-7phr2
I1111 22:30:27.464082   31588 round_trippers.go:427] Request Headers:
I1111 22:30:27.464095   31588 round_trippers.go:431]     Accept: application/json, */*
I1111 22:30:27.464105   31588 round_trippers.go:431]     User-Agent: kubectl/v1.19.3 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/1e11e4a
I1111 22:30:27.483934   31588 round_trippers.go:446] Response Status: 200 OK in 19 milliseconds
I1111 22:30:27.484300   31588 round_trippers.go:449] Response Headers:
I1111 22:30:27.484514   31588 round_trippers.go:452]     Cache-Control: no-cache, private
I1111 22:30:27.485035   31588 round_trippers.go:452]     Content-Type: application/json
I1111 22:30:27.485382   31588 round_trippers.go:452]     Date: Wed, 11 Nov 2020 22:30:27 GMT
I1111 22:30:27.486128   31588 request.go:1097] Response Body: {"kind":"Pod","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{"name":"boincclient-69cdf887dc-7phr2","generateName":"boincclient-69cdf887dc-","namespace":"default","selfLink":"/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/boincclient-69cdf887dc-7phr2","uid":"1f7ae333-07e5-429c-bb37-3430cc648170","resourceVersion":"683632","creationTimestamp":"2020-11-11T22:25:43Z","labels":{"app":"boincclient","pod-template-hash":"69cdf887dc"},"ownerReferences":[{"apiVersion":"apps/v1","kind":"ReplicaSet","name":"boincclient-69cdf887dc","uid":"b6e765bf-f38a-4c55-92a2-68ae87d8adef","controller":true,"blockOwnerDeletion":true}],"managedFields":[{"manager":"kube-controller-manager","operation":"Update","apiVersion":"v1","time":"2020-11-11T22:25:43Z","fieldsType":"FieldsV1","fieldsV1":{"f:metadata":{"f:generateName":{},"f:labels":{".":{},"f:app":{},"f:pod-template-hash":{}},"f:ownerReferences":{".":{},"k:{\"uid\":\"b6e765bf-f38a-4c55-92a2-68ae87d8adef\"}":{".":{},"f:apiVersion":{},"f:blockOwnerDeletion":{},"f:controller":{},"f:kind":{},"f:name":{},"f:uid":{}}}}, [truncated 4851 chars]
I1111 22:30:27.501641   31588 round_trippers.go:420] GET https://172.16.0.21:6443/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/boincclient-69cdf887dc-7phr2/log
I1111 22:30:27.501978   31588 round_trippers.go:427] Request Headers:
I1111 22:30:27.502183   31588 round_trippers.go:431]     Accept: application/json, */*
I1111 22:30:27.502463   31588 round_trippers.go:431]     User-Agent: kubectl/v1.19.3 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/1e11e4a
I1111 22:30:27.508414   31588 round_trippers.go:446] Response Status: 404 Not Found in 5 milliseconds
I1111 22:30:27.508462   31588 round_trippers.go:449] Response Headers:
I1111 22:30:27.508473   31588 round_trippers.go:452]     Cache-Control: no-cache, private
I1111 22:30:27.508501   31588 round_trippers.go:452]     Content-Type: application/json
I1111 22:30:27.508525   31588 round_trippers.go:452]     Content-Length: 270
I1111 22:30:27.508546   31588 round_trippers.go:452]     Date: Wed, 11 Nov 2020 22:30:27 GMT
I1111 22:30:27.508587   31588 request.go:1097] Response Body: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"the server could not find the requested resource ( pods/log boincclient-69cdf887dc-7phr2)","reason":"NotFound","details":{"name":"boincclient-69cdf887dc-7phr2","kind":"pods/log"},"code":404}
I1111 22:30:27.509597   31588 helpers.go:216] server response object: [{
  "metadata": {},
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "the server could not find the requested resource ( pods/log boincclient-69cdf887dc-7phr2)",
  "reason": "NotFound",
  "details": {
    "name": "boincclient-69cdf887dc-7phr2",
    "kind": "pods/log"
  },
  "code": 404
}]
F1111 22:30:27.509663   31588 helpers.go:115] Error from server (NotFound): the server could not find the requested resource ( pods/log boincclient-69cdf887dc-7phr2)
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

So the solution was to call entry point command from dockerfile.